# How to parse a JSON array in javascript that has a single quote around each object in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have a weird situation here. I have a text file that is a list of JSON objects and they are separated by line breaks like this:

```
{"upSpeed": 13.860419184316857, "downSpeed": 85.93058668830014, "time": "2016-12-12T21:31:56.507318"}
{"upSpeed": 13.860419184316857, "downSpeed": 85.93058668830014, "time": "2016-12-12T21:31:56.507318"}
{"upSpeed": 13.890492898595365, "downSpeed": 87.35392034236816, "time": "2016-12-12T21:37:52.174878"}
{"upSpeed": 13.69741910903317, "downSpeed": 88.08812682966898, "time": "2016-12-12T21:41:04.688231"}
...
```

I use `fs.readFile(text file)` to load that text file and then `array = data.split("\n")` to split the text file by line and then insert each line into `array`, creating a JSON array named `array`. But, the issue is when I split the original text file using `data.split("\n")`, the program wraps the resulting object in single quotes (`'`) on either side, resulting in invalid JSON. So, it ends up looking like this:

```
[ '{"upSpeed": 13.860419184316857, "downSpeed": 85.93058668830014, "time": "2016-12-12T21:31:56.507318"}',
  '{"upSpeed": 13.860419184316857, "downSpeed": 85.93058668830014, "time": "2016-12-12T21:31:56.507318"}',
  '{"upSpeed": 13.890492898595365, "downSpeed": 87.35392034236816, "time": "2016-12-12T21:37:52.174878"}',
  '{"upSpeed": 13.69741910903317, "downSpeed": 88.08812682966898, "time": "2016-12-12T21:41:04.688231"}'
...]
```

So, is there anyway to avoid the single quotes from being added in so the result is an actual javascript object? I have attempted to create a `for` loop and loop through each element in the array and run `array[i] = array[i].replace(/'/g, "");` to replace the single quotes with nothing (`""`) but that simply does not work and returns the same exact result shown above. Any ideas?

Comment: `JSON.parse("[" + data.split("\n").join(',') + "]")`

Comment: @Daniel that removes the double quotes around the string as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have "JSON with single quotes". You have a list of JSON strings. The single quotes are just node's way of writing that to the console.

Just parse each of them individually.

```
var items = data.split(/\n/).map(JSON.parse);
```

Recommended reading, because I suspect you are mixing up things: Ben Alman's blog - [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: That returns a `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: The file probably has a newline at the end, so `.split(/\n/)` leaves an empty string as the last element of the array, which would fail the last `JSON.parse`. `.trim()` should fix that: `var items = data.trim().split(/\n/).map(JSON.parse);`

Comment: @MichaelGeary has the right idea, but the returned JSON don't have the double quotes around the string

Comment: You really should read the link I provided, you seem to be confusing some really basic concepts here.

Comment: @Tomalak, thanks sorry for my ignorance, I read the article and understood that `JSON.parse` parses the JSON and JSON.stringify effectively removes the single quotes around the JSON string. My problem was that I was calling `JSON.stringify` inside the for loop, alongside the `JSON.parse` when the `JSON.stringify` had to be called outside the loop.

Comment: No, JSON.stringify does *not* "remove the single quotes". You really must sit down and work out the differences between JS data types (strings, numbers, objects etc), the differences between how node.js represents them when you print them to the console and what they actually are in the computer's memory,  and the difference between parsing and serialization. You have it all mixed up and you really need clear up that confusion.

Comment: @rakeshdas: Wait, you are _generating_ this line-by-line JSON data? You didn't mention that in your question. It sounded like you were getting the data already in this format from somewhere. This format is sometimes called [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) and is used by programs that want to be able to parse the JSON one line at a time. However, it's unlikely that you need this extra complication. As it sounds like you have discovered, you are better off generating the entire thing with a single `JSON.stringify()` and parsing it with a single `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: And yes, please take @Tomalak's comments to heart and study up on how all of this really works. It's not hard to understand, although there are some things that can be confusing like the way `console.log()` formats data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like : `var jsonItem = JSON.parse(array[i]);`